# TEXT entry control takes char as numeric SAS/AF

Tags: sas, sas-af

I am new to SAS/AF and SCL , i am trying to build Simple applications while learning, 
however when I enter a code in SCL with works fine with the Version 6 Objects but not for the latest components.

Here is the SCL code

```
INIT:                                                                                                                                   
return;                                                                                                                                 


BUTTON:                                                                                                                                 

SUBMIT CONTINUE;                                                                                                                        

proc print data=&datatable;                                                                                                             
run;                                                                                                                                    

ENDSUBMIT;                                                                                                                              

RETURN;                                                                                                                                 


TERM:                                                                                                                                   
Return;
```

This works fine for **Input Field**, which is Version 6 but not for the **Text Entry Control**

The error I get is when I enter **sashelp.class** is

```
NOTE: SCL source line.
17   proc print data=4427;
                 ----
                 22
                 200
ERROR 22-322: Expecting a name.
ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.
18   run;
ERROR: File WORK.NAME.DATA does not exist.
```

What is missing in the SCL script for the newer objects?

Comment: Is it related to the last post in [this](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/Getting-a-value-from-a-Text-Entry-Control-in-SAS-AF-App-for/td-p/34353/page/2) SAS Communites forum post?

Answer (score 1):

Submit replacement

- In Version 6 the submit replacement for an &ObjectName is its value.
- In Version 8+ the submit replacement for a &ControlName is its reference id, thus you get 4427 or whatever it is a frame runtime.

Change submit code in the button handler to reference the `text` attribute of the control in order to replace it with the attribute value.

```
proc print data=&datatable.text;
run;
```